# What do these terms mean in regards to a "reverse" dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

My assignment is:

Write a function reverse_dic(d) that takes a dictionary d as the input argument and returns a dictionary r. If the dictionary d has a key k and an associated value v, then the dictionary r should have a key v and a value k.

I understand what a dictionary is, it's something like:

```
dictionary = {'dog': 'woof', 'city': 'New York'}
```

But I don't understand what the question is asking for.

Comment: the reverse dictionary would return something like `dict = {'woof':'dog','New York':'city'}`

Comment: Be aware that if you have duplicate values you will lose data

Comment: I actually didn't understand your question and posted an answer. Sorry for that. Removed.

Comment: Oh, so that's what it's asking for. Thanks! :)